# Adding Attribute Route on Controller adds Parameter to Url

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to change the URL that will access my controller, but when I do, instead of getting **controller/action/id**,  I get **controller/action?id=**(the id number) in the URL.

I am using default routing in my MVC .Net Core.

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

On my controller I have `[Route("DifferentName/{action=index}")]` for attribute routing.

I have tried adding `[Route("DifferentName/{action=index}/{id?}")]`

but I get an exception "RoutePatternException: The route parameter name 'id' appears more than one time in the route template."

Answer (score 2):

These attributes are incorrect according to the documentation:

`[Route("DifferentName/{action=index}/{id?}")]`

`[Route("DifferentName/{action=index}")]`

This is how it should look like for controller when we want to only change its part of URL:

`[Route("DifferentName/[action]")]`
[action]

[action] will be replaced by your action name when asp .net core will be resolving URLs.

More information about routing and can be found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: I have tried `[Route("DifferentName/[action]")]` but still get ?id= in the URL. In addition if I try to navigate to DifferentName/Action/5 I get 404. I have to put DifferentName/Action?id=5.

Comment: I have also added `[Route("")] [Route("Index")]` to my Index action. The only way I can access it is by DifferentName/Index. DifferentName by its self throws 404. Which according to documentation it should work. Am I missing something??

Comment: My controller also inherits a base controller. I'm pretty sure that's effecting the routing. Going to do more research.

Answer (score 0):

> but I get an exception "RoutePatternException: The route parameter
> name 'id' appears more than one time in the route template."

I have reproduced your error. I need to confirm with you whether the reason for your error is to add Route attribute to `both controller and action`.

If so, as the exception points out, you don't need to specify route repeatedly.

Modify the following settings to implement the url like `'Differentname/action/5'`:

```
    [Route("DifferentName/{action=index}")]
    public class ShowPdfController : Controller
    {
       
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route("{id?}")]
        public IActionResult Action(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
   }
```

Then, you can see the test result of this setting:

[image]